# Bugatti Chiron - loose connection to wheels

Tags: technic, instructions, vehicle

I’m currently building this set and I notice that the connection to the front wheels often falls out. This is the small red line between the wheel and ball joint.

It depends on the angle. It is almost certain to come apart of you pull the wheel away from the body.

Is this resolved and held in place later in the build, or have I missed something?
[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmFXM.jpg[image][image]

Comment: Could you add additional picture from the inside of the hub in the situation shown on 2nd picture? Right now it looks like your CV joint seem to be a little too deep inside the hub.

Comment: I have added an additional photo. Does this help?

Comment: I  think you have the wheel at an angle which is out of the range of angles the finished model will be able to do

Comment: It would be best to remove thin 5L liftarms/beams to see the connection between CV joint and hub.

Comment: I’ve added another photo. I’m holding it at the tightest point. The images in the instruction manual show the two grey parts touching, with no red bar visible.

Comment: I was wondering if it was just a range of movement that wouldn’t be possible once assembled. It makes construction somewhat fiddly as it tends to fall out!

Comment: That's intended. When you have your spring compressed driving axle becomes shorter. This actual CV joint is designed not to have no friction with an axle and allow some freedom to move.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see a gap between the grey part and the black part. They should be flush picture 1. Normally it take some force to assemble these hub parts.

[image]

If you look to the back side of the "back" side you must see the clip of the grey as 
picture 2.

[image]

The grey part must rotate freely so if you apply some force to if and have it slow down if its own it must continue to rotate for some seconds until it stops

Comment: You’re exactly right. I took a look at it this morning with w clear head and realised that these bits snapped together. 

Came here to answer my own question and you’ve helpfully beat me to it. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, I was having the same problem. I did not push hard enough to get the 2 pieces locked together. Thanks for posting the question and thanks for the answer